# With MS Graph API is there a way to search a group calendar and return meeting time even if only one of the group member is available?

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have to create a Microsoft Graph API to search a group's calendar. But want to have a meeting with any one person available at that time. What would be the possible way to do that?

Comment: The closest i see is that trying the Getschedule() API. Have you tried it? Here's the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule

Comment: I actually tried findmeetingtimes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http but I am not getting a solution as to how can I get a time returned even if any one person in a group is available. So I want to put for eg 5 people as attendees but only want one of them in the meeting.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you can use either Findmeetingstimes() or GetSchedule() to do so - they will return you the availability info for the users.  If you believe this a new feature which Microsoft needs to consider implementing, then file a Microsoft uservoice; here's the link -. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=getschedule

Answer (score 0):

- You can use either [Findmeetingstimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)() or [GetSchedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-free-busy-schedule)() to do so - they will return you the availability info for the users.
- If you believe this a new feature which Microsoft needs to consider
  implementing, then file a Microsoft uservoice; [here's the link for it](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?query=getschedule).